# how to detect the origin of a memory error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory

i'm using visual studio 2003 and i have a c++  application using microsoft STL that have a memory error :

the code was :

```
instrcutions;
function1();
function2();
...
functionN();
```

i modify it :

```
list<A*> l1;
instrcutions;
function1();
function2();
...
functionN();
```

in execution in debug mode, i see the size of the list growing, become smaller and the data the list point changes of coourse.

as the functions "don't know" the list exist, the list can't be modified in purpose.
i tried changing the name of the list : the same behaviour occurs.

any idea of what can cause this trouble, where to search in the code, and maybe free tools to track wrong memory access.

can someone confirm that visual studio can not detect wrong memory access as i described ?

Comment: In Linux, you can and should use `valgrind`. If your code is portable, you can just compile it with GCC on a Linux machine and test it for errors there. Note that having a container whose element type is a pointer is an open invitation for trouble, and you have to write this sort of code *very* carefully.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `visual-c++` if it is Visual Studio specific?

Comment: "element type is a pointer is an open invitation for trouble, and you have to write this sort of code very carefully." the code is full of it !...

Comment: there some windows dlls(I don't have the code of them) and thousands of lines of code specific to visual c++. I don't think it is easily possible to make it work in linux.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the list should not be affected by any of the functions unless you pass a refrence or a pointer to the list to some of the functions.  Also what you describe is not the general way in which memory issues exhibit themselves.  The list decreasing in good order is an indication of undesired use of functionality of the list a memory issue would cause a crash the list to be null for no reason or some other type of "weird" issue.

Comment: "The list decreasing in good order is an indication of undesired use of functionality of the list ". you mean that the code handle the memory where is stored l1 as a list (even if this mmemory is not allocated)? stranger, I created another list l2 in the same place of the program, the same thing happens to l2 !

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself the following questions:

1. Are the pointers being stored in the `list` pointing to objects on the heap or on the stack?
2. Are you `delete`ing or `free`ing the pointers in the `list`, and do allocations match deallocations?
3. Do you really need pointers or can you just use value types?

You could use `shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer if you are having trouble with keeping track of #2 (make sure you don't have cyclic references though).

Comment: I do not touch the list ! that s the wierd thing. it remains empty. the only instruction that uses the list its the declaration "list<A*> l1;" I need pointers... in addition to this problem, there is other lists pointing structs in the heap that are modified also without calling them explicitly.

Comment: But you said: _"in execution in debug mode, i see the size of the list growing, become smaller and the data the list point changes of coourse."_ How is that possible if you didn't touch it?

Comment: Are you doing pointer arithmetic with pointers pointing to the stack? If so, the bug will be in that code.

Comment: " How is that possible if you didn't touch it?" this is the terrible question !!! i can declare another list in the same function. it is also modified without beeing "touched" by the code !!

Comment: "Are you doing pointer arithmetic with pointers pointing to the stack?" no

Comment: my idea is that a portion of code uses a lot of pointers of deallocated memory( or badly allocated) without knowing that these memories are deallocated. so the list i create is putten in this "conflict" memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question - are you modifying the list at all? Passing it to any functions?

If you're sure you are overwriting memory somewhere, try using the [_heapchk()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xse74he%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) function while running in debug mode. I've successfully used it for detecting memory overwrites by wrapping important statements with std::couts and calls to _heapchk():

```
std::cout << "Loc 0" << std::endl;
callFunction(parameter);
_heapchk();
std::cout << "Loc 1" << std::endl;
```

This may help you locate *where* in your code the memory overwrite occurs, but not why.

Comment: nope : no modifying it and no passing it to any function. thx for _heapchk()

Answer (score 0):

The list's content is pointers to Objects of type A however.. this is a guess because your problem seems very general, have you thought about that the list object isnt a pointer so when your creating your objects to pass into the list object. That the list object no longer exists because you have push it further down on the stack. Perhaps make your list object..

```
 list<A*>* l1;
```

Comment: making a list objects : list<A> l1; works fine. but i need list<A*> l1; because of polymorphism. in need to put substructures in the list.

Comment: but overall, this problem signals a memory error of some king of error that have to be solved.

Comment: Memory error, are by any chance are you trying to access element in your list that dont exist. You know that when you do  list<A*> your not creating any objects your just creating pointers to objects.

So all you have at the moment is a cup that is empty and you are trying to get water out of the cup. But there isnt any, so this will give you a memory error. 

So what you need to do is every time you want to add a new object to your list put:
list<A*> cup; //This is an empty cup
A* water1 = new A();
cup.push_front(water1);

Comment: i know. it is what i do for other lists.

Comment: cup.size() give 0, then 1 ....then 5, then 4, etc. without touching the list... but the list points to inexistant objects of course.

Comment: Have you tried putting the list itself on the heap so.. list<A*>* cup;
cup = new list<A*>;

Answer (score 0):

list l1;
as far as i remember list contains it's size for fast .size() function work, this can be used.

I just don't remember whether vs2003 supports breakpoints on memory write. VS2005 - definitely does.

So the idea: get address of 'size' member inside the list (find it by opening  header file) and set the breakpoint on data change. You will catch violator in any case then, nevertheless it's usual hidden push_back or write to a random stack memory where std::list object itself presents.